# Magento 2.4.6p2 Order confirmation emails not sending when customer places an order

Tags: magento2.4

I have installed "Payplus" payment gateway on Magento 2.4.6p2. When tried to place a test order the order is received fine in admin however the customer doesn't receive an order confirmation email and an email is not sent at all from smtp. The actual extension is conflicting with the entire payment options as non of the payment options do not send order confirmation when the order is placed. When sending email manually from admin it works fine. When deleting the extension of Payplus everything is working fine again and order confirmation automatically sends out after placing an order. Please advise what should be fixed in which file and how. Your help will be highly appreciate it.

Comment: Ask the extension vendor for the support of this.

Comment: Please review the site logs when placing an order. It seems that enabling that module is causing an error. Are you able to navigate to the success order page as well?

Comment: When I place a test order it works fine all payment methods are working fine and the order is completed. The only thing is when the actual extension is installed then there is no order confirmation email received after placing an order. When I disable the extension the issue still exist. Only when I completely remove the extension then everything is working again and order confirmation is sent.